# Error: class uri 'egg:meinheld#gunicorn_worker' invalid or not found:

Tags: ubuntu, flask, gunicorn

am using FROM tiangolo/meinheld-gunicorn-flask:python3.8 AS build-image

although it is giving the below error on Ubuntu 22.04

Error: class uri 'egg:meinheld#gunicorn_worker' invalid or not found:

````
{"loglevel": "debug", "workers": 4, "bind": "0.0.0.0:80", "workers_per_core": 0.5, "host": "0.0.0.0", "port": "80"}
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 71, in load_class
return pkg_resources.load_entry_point(dist, section, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 474, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 2846, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 2450, in load
return self.resolve()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 2456, in resolve
module = import(self.module_name, fromlist=['name'], level=0)
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/meinheld/init.py", line 1, in
from meinheld.server import *
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/meinheld/server.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
]```
````